# Returning multiple SELECT queries in single array

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, http, select

I am writing angularjs application that relies on data returned from MySQL database.

Angularjs code makes a HTTP request and logs the returned data to the console:

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: 'php/return_something.php', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //The API call to the back-end was successful (i.e. a valid session)
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error.");
    });
```

*return_something.php*

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST."; dbname=".DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(id_table_x) from table_x; SELECT count(id_table_y) from table_y;");
    $sql->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($results);
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br />" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

To the console an array with one element gets logged.

> [Object]

Inside this object there is a result of the first query (*"SELECT count(id_table_x) from table_x"*).

What should I change that I would see the result of the second query (*"SELECT count(id_table_y) from table_y"*) as the second element of this array? Any help appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK PDO does not support multiple queries inside a single prepared statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write two queries, which is also more readable (imho):

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(id_table_x) from table_x;");
$sql->execute();

$sql2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(id_table_y) from table_y;");
$sql2->execute();

$results[] = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$results[] = $sql2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

EDIT: 
`$results[] =` is a shortcut for `$results.push()`. Before, you have to define $results an an array:

```
$results = array();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not make multiple SELECT statement in one query.
Another way:

```
SELECT count(id_table_x) from table_x UNION SELECT count(id_table_y) from table_y;
```

OR

```
SELECT "table_x" as tableName, count(id_table_x) as nbID from table_x UNION SELECT "table_y" as tableName, count(id_table_y) as nbID from table_y;
```

You will these datas

```
tableName | nbID
==========|======
table_x   | 6
table_y   | 1
```

Full code:

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST."; dbname=".DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT "table_x" as tableName, count(id_table_x) as nbID from table_x UNION SELECT "table_y" as tableName, count(id_table_y) as nbID from table_y;');
    $sql->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($results);
    /*
        [
            {'tableName':'table_x', 'nbID': 6},
            {'tableName':'table_y', 'nbID': 42}
        ]
    */
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $sql . "<br />" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```